# How to read configSections

Tags: c#, app-config

I've set up some custom config sections in my App.Config, such that I now have a configSection that looks like this.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="Section1" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>    
    <section name="Section2" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>    
    <section name="Section3" type="ConfigSections.MySection, MyNamespace"/>    
</configSections>
```

What I want to do is to read *this section* in code in order to find out at runtime what sections I have. I have tried:

```
var mySections = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("configSections");
```

but this returns null. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I cannot find anything about how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: It think you have to do it like this: var mySections = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Section1");

Comment: To clarify, I am perfectly happy how to read the section called "Section1". I am trying to read the section called "configSections", so I don't have to hardcode the text "Section1" in my code. The reason for this is that I don't know at runtime what or how many sections I'm going to have.

Comment: To put it another way, I want to be able to read the "name" attribute, on each of the "section" elements, contained in the "configSections" element (above), in my App.Config. (This is hard to explain!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`Configuration.Sections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.configuration.sections%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)-property to get the names of the declared configuration sections. Then, optionally if you need, use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` to retrieve an individual section.

Note that you may want to use the value of the [`SectionInformation.IsDeclared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.isdeclared%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or `ConfigSource` of the respective [`ConfigurationSection.SectionInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.sectioninformation%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to find out of the section was actually declared in your configuration file, or is inherited from `machine.config` or otherwise.

Example:

```
    var cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var localSections = cfg.Sections.Cast<ConfigurationSection>()
       .Where(s => s.SectionInformation.IsDeclared);
```

Finally, note that this approach will only get you configuration sections. It will not return configuration sections, which are itself inside a `<sectionGroup>`. For them, you would first need iterate over `Configuration.SectionGroups`, which has it's own [`Sections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroup.sections%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)-property that contains the per section group sections. It can also contain nested section groups, again accessible via the [`SectionGroups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.configurationsectiongroup.sectiongroups%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property of each `ConfigurationSectionGroup` instance.

Comment: Thankyou. That appears to be exactly what I need. Cheers!

Comment: I guess the first sentence of the last paragraph  is trying to say, "This approach will get you root-level configuration sections, but not configuration sections which are nested inside a `<sectionGroup>`."

Answer (score 0):

if put all the sections into a section group this would work:

```
<configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="FMGlobal.Common.SecuritySubsystem.ADAzManFeed">
        <section name="ADFolders" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

  var  NVC = (ConfigurationManager.GetSection( _
    "FMGlobal.Common.SecuritySubsystem.ADAzManFeed")
```