# Merging custom configuration sections at runtime in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, configurationmanager

My question is about working with standard .NET configuration objects and custom configuration elements as well, (which one can define by extending the [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class). We usually obtain these from the [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class's methods, [`GetSection(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) being an example.

The loaded configuration object appears to be a *merged* configuration object containing the setup present in the application config file (the the **app.config** or **web.config** file which a developer may have created) and what is defined in the **machine.config** file (the latter coming with the .NET Framework installation).

So, we can assume that the configuration is loaded in hierarchical manner with the **machine.config** first, and any user-defined configuration overlaying that default setup, and could be looked at like this:

- **machine.config**
- **app.config** (overrides / merges with respective elements found in machine.config )

My goal is to create multiple layers of configuration, so that there might be other config files between (and if possible, after) the **machine.config** and the **app.config** file:

- **machine.config**

  - ***custom.config*** (a custom config interfering between the machine.config and the app.config file)

    - **app.config** - now **app.config** is merged with both **machine.config** and **custom.config**

---

**Update**

The point with that is - if I have defined the configuration section in both **custom.config** and **app.config**, I need to get a merged version of both configs when I call `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyCustomSection")`. Ideally, it will be great if I am able to perform merging as described in [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markgabarra/configuration-merge-behavior) or use [Wayback machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20101114182148/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markgabarra/archive/2006/06/27/648742.aspx)

---

Normally, I would write my own configuration manager class and will try to get as far as I could to get the desired result, but assuming the .NET framework has this working for **machine.config** and **app.config**, I thought I might benefit from the built-in functionality of the framework. In addition, I do not know how to manually trigger such merging, if I am indeed supposed to resort to a config manager implementation of my own.

So, is it possible to leverage the built-in mechanisms of configuration section/element merging with custom configuration files? I am especially interested in developing and supporting this for custom configuration sections. The `System.Configuration` namespace contains base objects to build configuration section and elements, and those allow some settings related to the merging (like setting the appropriate [`ConfigurationElementCollectionType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollectiontype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example). Are these related to only merging with **machine.config** (or multiple layers of **web.config** files in a web application), or is it possible to manually trigger the merging of pre-loaded config files? I am trying to avoid having to support custom merging in any of my custom configuration objects and probably forget about supporting the existing settings from the System.Configuration...

---

**Update**

There is an important clarification to I'd like to make, in response to the existing answers and comments. I am capable of loading the `ConfigurationSection` objects from the current application setup (**app.config** / **web.config**) and from a physical file that is my **custom.config**. I need to know if there is a chance to merge these objects without resorting to reflection and property-by-property comparison, by some built-in means in the framework.

---

<sup>**Note:** I would appreciate better a solution that would work on .NET 3.0+. Please add a note if your answer targets a higher version of the framework.</sup>

Comment: I am looking forward to seeing answers to this question. But I fear that what you're asking for is not possible. The .NET configuration system is not super flexible when it comes to configuration file splitting / modularization.

Comment: @stakx, maybe you're correct. Still, since the .NET framework itself exposes merging capabilities (and does this merging internally), it must be possible to at least understand how it all happens. I have managed to do a lot for easing the configuration in most of my projects, yet still this merging capability is the missing piece of the puzzle I am looking for from a long time.

Comment: This is not an exact answer to the question, but you could use external satellite config files with the configSource attribute: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier, thank you for the hint. However, this seems to help in splitting the config file into more convenient locations (unless I am missing something). I am more interested in layering the settings between different config files with similar structure - for instance if both app.config and custom.config defined element 'custom element', I need to obtain a merged version of it from both files. when I use `ConfigurationManager.GetSection(...)`. I hope this clarifies my requirement a little more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [silver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128439/silver) has pointed out, a well configured `ExeConfigurationFileMap` could do the job, at a certain cost.

I have taken his example and made a working version of it.

Here are the two config files I have merged for my test purposes:

**custom.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="custom" type="..." />
  </configSections>
  <custom>
    <singleProperty id="main" value="BaseValue" />
    <propertyCollection>
      <property id="1" value="One" />
      <property id="4" value="Four" />
    </propertyCollection>
  </custom>
</configuration>
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="custom" type="..."/>
  </configSections>
  <custom>
    <singleProperty id="main" value="OverriddenValue" />
    <propertyCollection>
      <property id="1" value="OverridenOne" />
      <property id="2" value="Two" />
      <property id="3" value="Three" />
    </propertyCollection>
  </custom>
</configuration>
```

And I used the following code to test the merged setup:

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.MachineConfigFilename = PathToCustomConfig;
map.ExeConfigFilename = PathToAppConfig;
                
var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
        map, 
        ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var section = configuration.GetSection("custom") as CustomConfigSection;
Assert.IsNotNull(section);

Assert.AreEqual(section.SingleProperty.Value, "OverriddenValue");
Assert.AreEqual(section.PropertyCollection.Count, 4);
// Needed to map the properties as dictionary, not to rely on the property order
var values = section.PropertyCollection
        .Cast<SimpleConfigElement>()
        .ToDictionary(x => x.ID, x => x.Value);
Assert.AreEqual(values["1"], "OverridenOne");
Assert.AreEqual(values["2"], "Two");
Assert.AreEqual(values["3"], "Three");
Assert.AreEqual(values["4"], "Four");
```

#### pros of this approach

- I get the built-in merging logic to work
- Works for older versions of .NET (tested on 3.5)
- No need for reflection or other **black magic** stuff to trigger the behavior.

#### cons

- Not very sure, but by setting `map.MachineConfigFilename = PathToCustomConfig;` I assume I am removing any values that are set up by the real `machine.config` file. This could be error-prone and should be avoided for web applications, as most of them rely on what's in the real `machine.config`
- One needs to pass the location of the application configuration file, as it is no longer determined automatically. Thus one needs to figure out how the `app.config` will be named when the code is compiled (usually AssemblyName.exe.config)
- You can merge the contents of *two only* files that way. If one needs a larger hierarchy, then this will not work well.

I am still in the process of refining the technique, thus I will return to update this post once done.

Comment: How does this work with appSettings? I get invalid cast error when it tries to load appsettings. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

> The .NET configuration system is not super flexible

That comment nails it and explains why you've been looking for a long time and haven't found anything yet.  Not all the .NET Framework parts are "good", System.Configuration deserves the spot on the far bottom.  It is ridiculously over-engineered for something that's ultimately a simple task but at the same time turned into something exceedingly inflexible.  Hard to reverse-engineer how this happened, I *think* it got paralyzed by security concerns.  Somewhat understandable perhaps, commandeering a program with data is always a considerable risk.

The only extension point that I know about is writing your own [SettingsProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.settingsprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The framework has only one for general usage, the LocalFileSettingProvider class.  Also exceedingly inflexible, there isn't any way to alter its behavior.  There is a decent example available for a custom setting provider, the [RegistrySettingsProvider sample](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms181001%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) demonstrates a provider that stores settings in the registry.  It can be a good starting point for writing your own.

Not exactly what you have in mind perhaps, do scratch the idea that you can break into the layering inside System.Configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the honest answer and I appreciate the sample link, I will take look into it. I admit I am kinda disappointed to learn it is indeed so inflexible, the System Configuration. It really seemed to have the potential for my goals, but as if it was "playing hard to get". I should have been thinking of alternatives now, if I was not that stubborn..., but that's another tale

Comment: I have updated my post, btw. Does the scenario I mention now make any difference, or is still that impossible.

Comment: Hmya, you do very rapidly get to a point where it just make no sense anymore to use it at all.  Hunting down the specific .config file by yourself is certainly something you never *really* want to do.

Answer (score 5):

have a look on the following code that knows to load your configurations or the exe configuration.
once the following code will be clear to you you can customize the loading and the merging as you wish (loading it twice and overriding one with the other).

```
private static void InitConfiguration()
{
    var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
    var AssemblyConfigFile = "";
    if (File.Exists(AssemblyConfigFile))
        map.ExeConfigFilename = AssemblyConfigFile;
    else
        map.ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]+".config");

    var Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    var serviceModelSectionGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(Configuration);

}
```

Comment: Hi, it seems your idea got me even closer to what I desire. Checkout my [wiki post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028171/merging-custom-configuration-sections-at-runtime-in-net/30236464#30236464) to this question. I'd be glad if you can elaborate on some of the cons - particularly If I am losing what is in `machine.config`, and if I can have more than 2 files merged. I tried to work with `RoamingUserConfigFilename` but it seemed not to work.

Comment: if you have the same key in the machine config and in the app config then your app will get your app values. 
you can use:
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyName"];
the values that you have only in the machine config will be available also after that kind of merge.

Comment: The point is that when I create the `ExeConfigurationFileMap` I am explicitly saying `map.MachineConfigFilename = PathToCustomConfig`. The point is that the exe config is merged with what I say to be the machine config. Shouldn't this ignore the real `machine.config` or am I missing something?

Comment: you're right it doesn't make sense, I don't know why it's working but it is, the values that exist in the machine.config and doesn't appear in your configurations will be available after that override. (I've tried also to use a different constructor to the ExeConfigurationFileMap)
please let me know if you find the reason why it's working.

Comment: I will try to investigate why it is so, but my wild guess it is there is an internal .NET logic that makes sure the machine config is always taken into account. I suppose there are settings which are not meant to be available via custom app/web config files, and without these the .NET framework might be unable to operate. In fact, I am glad it is still taken into account, as I could benefit from the approach in a web application as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 3 levels of configuration inheritance by default: Machine, Exe and User (which can be Roaming or Local). If you're loading the configuration files yourself you can use the [ExeConfigurationFileMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.execonfigurationfilemap(v=vs.110).aspx) class in combination with [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx) to load your own custom configuration hierarchy.

I don't think you can change where the default paths are for the ConfigurationManager class with this, but you will get a Configuration element which can be used to get whatever sections from the loaded config hierarchy.

If you check out the answer to [How to read configSections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331844/how-to-read-configsections) it includes some notes on determining at what level sections were declared in the hierarchy (using SectionInformation)

```
var localSections = cfg.Sections.Cast<ConfigurationSection>()
       .Where(s => s.SectionInformation.IsDeclared);
```

Comment: Although this does not answer my question, I must thank you for the hint it provides - if I am able to detect which sections have been declared in **custom.config** and **app.config** (seems your answer addresses that part quite well), I will already have the exact section objects I need to merge. Now I should find a way to trigger that ... merging.

Comment: My bad, it seems you are actually answering my question indirectly, as the `ExeConfigurationFileMap` was indeed the way to go, it just seemed a little wrong to (ab)use it in the way I wanted. Still, I fear I will hardly find an alternative, and you deserve some credit or pointing this to me.

Answer (score 0):

we may need to use the classes
ConfigurationSection and ConfigurationProperty

Please refer below link for the details on the implementation
https://blog.danskingdom.com/adding-and-accessing-custom-sections-in-your-c-app-config/