# Saltstack - Merge two files

Tags: salt-stack

I have 2 configuration files which must be merged before I run some commands on top of the final config file.
Is there a way in Saltstack in which I can merge files easily ?

I tried the below code and it did not work.

```
{% set source_config_file = 'data/file-extra.conf' %}

app_config_block:
  file.blockreplace:
    - name: /etc/app.conf
    - marker_start: "### START : Appliance Statusd ###"
    - marker_end: "### END : Appliance Statusd ###"
    - append_if_not_found: True
    - show_changes: True
    - content: |
        {% include source_config_file %}
```

Comment: See please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028171/merging-custom-configuration-sections-at-runtime-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Using the method shown in the question, you should be able to get the contents of `file-extra.conf` into `app.conf`.

But for that you'll need to use the `read` function of Salt [file module](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.file.html#salt.modules.file.read).

```
{% set extra_conf = salt.file.read('data/file-extra.conf') %}

app_config_block:
  file.blockreplace:
    - name: /etc/app.conf
    - marker_start: "### START : Appliance Statusd ###"
    - marker_end: "### END : Appliance Statusd ###"
    - append_if_not_found: True
    - show_changes: True
    - content: {{ extra_conf }}
```

One thing to note, is that `data/file-extra.conf` will be expected to reside on the Salt master.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load a text file into a variable and then appending it to another file, you can use:

```
{% import_text "data/file-extra.conf" as file_extra %}

app_config_block:
  file.blockreplace:
    - name: /etc/app.conf
    - marker_start: "### START : Appliance Statusd ###"
    - marker_end: "### END : Appliance Statusd ###"
    - append_if_not_found: True
    - show_changes: True
    - content: {{ file_extra | yaml_encode }}
```

`yaml_encode` will prevent any formatting issues when importing `file-extra.conf` content.